# I have a script I'm trying to put on the character but it won't let me?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Alright, so I'm working in Unity for a class and I'm doing the 3D Survival Shooter tutorial. I just finished making the Player Movement script and I'm trying to test it out, but when I press the play button, it says "All compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter playmode!"

I was looking at the bottom and saw in the console that the error I have says: "Assets/_Complete-Game/MobileInput/Scripts/MobileControlRig.cs(12,29): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IActiveBuildTargetChanged' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor.Build'. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

I've never used Unity before, so I have no idea what to do. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Things to note: I'm using Unity 5.6.0f3 Personal, and my computer's on Windows 7 (it's a school computer so we can't update them).

Comment: What's your Unity version?

Comment: I edited that in just now. I'm also not sure if this question has been asked before.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1396260/error-cs0234-the-type-or-namespace-name-iactivebui-1.html

Answer (score 3):

`IActiveBuildTargetChanged` is not available. That's causing the error.

You are using *Unity 5.6.0f3* but `IActiveBuildTargetChanged` was added in *Unity 2017.1*. You need to download Unity 2017.1 or version above this in order to follow this tutorial.

Comment: I don't understand. The tutorial I'm doing was done in version 4.6. (It has steps to updating things to Unity 5, and I was going to do that afterward.) It should also be noted that the school computers I'm using won't let us update (at least, as far as the teachers know).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks to the commenter who linked me to a Unity Forums website.

What I got from it was you can avoid having that error by going in the script and deleting the lines "#if UNITY_EDITOR , UnityEditor.Build.IActiveBuildTargetChanged #endif:".
And if it happens in any of the other scripts, just delete it from them too.

Thanks for your help, everyone!